# Why do the insert and substring String methods not accept an unsigned 64 bit integer as an argument?

Tags: c#, .net, string, indexing

Why do the String methods, Insert and Substring, expect a signed 32 bit integer when it is possible that the number of characters in a given string can surpass the maximum value of a signed 32 bit integer? Would you please provide an example of negative indexing and how it would be used? If I run into a situation whereby the number of characters is well over the maximum value of a signed 32 bit integer, do I need to overload the Substring and Insert methods or there is already something that handles such situations in the .NET framework?

Comment: I am working on a personal project that involves a text processor so I was wondering since it is a possibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implicit cast between `uint` and `int`, the latter of which is very, *very* commonly used everywhere else in the .NET libraries.

Forcing explicit casts here are a lot less user friendly than having the possibility of an invalid argument. As to the length of the characters: I think you'll run into other problems creating a string with over 2 billion characters.